# Django and PHP together

Tags: django, django-models

```
def hi_guys():
 question=" I have a django application and a php script. I want that php script
 interacts with the tables used by django ( with INSERT and DELETE ). Are there 
 problems with django ?

 Thanks <:-)"


 print question
```

Comment: `def attention_xRobot(): if (accept_rate = 0): print "you should try to fix that"`

Comment: If no-one is seeing your question, it's because you forgot to call `hi_guys()`

Comment: @Anthony Forloney: your 'if' condition set accept_rate to 0. You might want to use 0==accept_rate to avoid errors like this.

Comment: the original will raise a `SyntaxError`. just use `if not accept_rate:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you keep the data correct(responding to the django model rules) everything will be ok.

P.S. Have in mind that if you don`t use transactions it is possible that django and php queries to mix in order, if this is significant to your system

Comment: You right. I will use transaction for tables shared by django and php ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you just want two different applications, one of them PHP and the other Python/Django to interact with the same database?
That is a relatively common occurrence.  It is really more of a question of the database you are planning to use than the applications that will be accessing it.

What database are you planning to use?

Comment: Yes, I want that django and php interacts with the same database. I am going to use postgresql <:-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issues with that. We have an application where I'm doing that; people interact with the PHP front end and fetch data from an API, and then the widget that displays it is written in Django. As long as each is making valid queries and writes to the DB, it doesn't really matter if you're accessing it through PHP or Python.

Answer (score 1):

no problems at all

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySql, SQLite or PostgreSQL, and then the problem is solved ?